# cannot select select2 remote ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

i cannot select my select2 result from ajax. anyone can help me? This is my code

```
$("#city_from").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: base_url+$('#city_from').attr('data-url'),
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 1000,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                departure: params.term, // search term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
            return {
                results: data.airport,
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    placeholder: "Enter airport/city",
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    templateResult: function(data) {
        if (data.loading) return data.text;
        return data;
    },
    templateSelection: function(data) {
        return data;
    }
}).ready(function () {
    $(".select2-selection__placeholder").text("Enter airport/city")
});
```

The result from my code is only the dropdown, but it cannot selected.
Thank you.

Comment: can you post the html where the `.select2` div is please

Comment: @Tommy Please post the sample JSON data which you get from the url